# Stop the webcam after it detects a specific color

Tags: python, opencv, colors, webcam, color-detection

I have written a code which detects light pink color. Now i want to add a code which would automatically close the webcam after it detects the light pink color. Can you help me with this one?
Here's the **EDITED** code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(1):
    _, frame = cap.read()

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    lower_pink = np.array([160,50,50])
    upper_pink = np.array([180,255,255])

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_pink, upper_pink)

    # Bitwise-AND mask and original image
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame, mask= mask)
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
    cv2.imshow('res',res)
    break

if(cv2.countNonZero(mask) > 0):
    print("FOUND")
    raise SystemExit

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You can exit when your mask says you've found the pink color (i.e. at least some amount of pixels in the mask are non zero). Something like; `if(cv2.countNonZero(mask) > threshold): break`

Comment: I am new to image processing and all these. So can you please add what threshold value I should write?
Because when I put it to zero and run the code. The window(hsv,mask,res) just closes in milliseconds.

Comment: What is the minimum size of your pink blob? You should make sure not to close because of some noisy pink points. You can set it to 10, 20, 50, 100 and see what works the best. A better approach would be to get the dimension of the largest blob in the mask, and exit it it's large enough. This will be more robust to noisy points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loop with an unconditional `break` (and no possible `continue`) doesn't make sense because then it is semantically no loop.

The test has to be within the loop, because you want to apply it to each captured image until you hit the first with enough pink in it.  And then `break` the loop.  Don't exit the program here, because then the clean up code after the loop isn't executed anymore.  Exiting by raising `SystemExit` is a bit strange anyway, that's what the `sys.exit()` function is meant to do.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def main():
    lower_pink = np.array([160, 50, 50])
    upper_pink = np.array([180, 255, 255])
    threshold = 100  # TODO Adapt to your needs.
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
        _, frame = cap.read()
        hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
        mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_pink, upper_pink)
        masked = cv2.bitwise_and(frame, frame, mask=mask)
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
        cv2.imshow('masked', masked)
        # if cv2.countNonZero(mask) > threshold:
        #     print('FOUND')
        #     break
        print(cv2.countNonZero(mask))
        # 
        # Wait for escape key.
        # 
        if cv2.waitKey(500) == 27:
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The actual threshold test is commented out and replaced by printing the pixel count of the mask so you can determine which value would suit your needs.

Comment: Hey thank you for correcting me. I'm a beginner.

Code did work fine but the problem is it's not even showing the mask and result window and I'm getting FOUND message in a matter of milliseconds. I even tried to change the threshold value but same result. Is the code working fine or there is some problem?

Comment: I've changed the code so you can test how many pixels the mask has under different circumstances (objects, lighting, …).